# Save graph from R as editable graphic in Excel

Tags: excel, r, user-interface

I am writing a GUI in R, and one of the functions I must implement is a button to save graphical output to an Excel sheet, ideally the graphic should be editable in Excel. I am trying to do this the following way:

1. Save data used for graph to an .xlsx file
2. Call a VBA scrip from R to recreate the graph in the .xlsx file.

I am stuck with step two, as I dont know how to execute a vba scrip from R. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: assuming it's on windows, there is some WMF/EMF (windows/extended metafile) format support, although my vague memory is that it's a little bit glitchy.  See http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-misc:export , http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devEMF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up the sheet as a template and then create the graph and linking it to a specific area on the sheet or another sheet. Then when you need to create a new file, copy the template and add the data from R to Excel and then the graph will update with the new data.

If you want to use VBA then the method I generally use is [StatconnDCOM](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html#statconnDCOM) + RCOM and just address Excel as a COM object.